# How to make my installer install XNA framework and .NET 4.0

Tags: xna-4.0, monogame

I have made a simple Monogame game. Right now I am using this installation-package maker: http://installforge.net/

Currently my installer only installs my "game". (All the output files generated by the build)

However I also want it to install the XNA framework 4.0

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20914

and the .NET Framework 4.0

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718

How would I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to install xna framework on the users machine ?

Comment: @Shiro So my game can run. I believe Monogame games still need XNA to run on the user's machine. Am I wrong? In any case I still need to know how to install the .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: as far as i know, xna framework is a developers only tool, as for the .net framework 4.0 is just an update on windows which pretty much everyone already has, i have noticed that .net framework 3.5 works on windows xp, and .net framework 4.0 or above does not... but who uses that anymore

Comment: @Shiro Still some people might now have .NET 4.0 and I am quite sure that XNA framework is not just a dev tool it has all the XNA libraries that the user needs. Do you know how to answer my question?

Comment: i unfortunately don't, i searched it last night specifically for monogame because i am using it myself as well and haven't found any information yet, i will post an answer if i find anything. luckily this doesn't matter for android applications i guess since all you need is the .apk. i am almost 100% sure that you don't need to install the .net framework since it comes with windows, but i don't know about the xna framework

Comment: Have you tried this project? [link](http://xnainstaller.codeplex.com/) It seems to do exactly what you are asking for and is open-source.

Comment: @vroomvsr check out my answer here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/97884/xna-game-publishing-help-with-incompatibilities-via-content-built-at-runtime/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using Forge as my installation package maker I decided to use Inno Installer in the end.

http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

In Inno installer you can include the .NET installer in your bundle of files and then make a command to run the installer.

Answer (score 2):

MonoGame based games do NOT require the XNA framework to run. The XNA namespaces in your MonoGame code are named as such for compatibility purposes.

In fact, the lat4est versions of MonoGame also no longer require XNA at development time.

Please download the latest MonoGame build: http://www.monogame.net/downloads/

To force an install of the .NET Framework, you have to set it as a dependency in your installer package, and you may need to download and link to the .NET 4.0 runtime installer.